# OxyPlot - Why can't I programmatically see points in a series?

Tags: c#, vb.net, oxyplot

I add points to a new `LineSeries` using `series.Points.AddRange`.

This series is then added to the `PlotModel`.

When I then do `plotModel.Series(0).`, there's no `Points` property to select the points from. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the `Series` property is a generic Series, which doesn't have the concept of `Points` (which makes sense, as other types of Series might not).

To get the `Points` out, you need to cast the `Series` to a `LineSeries`:

`CType(PlotModel.Series(0), LineSeries).Points`

`((LineSeries)PlotModel.Series(0)).Points`